# Using any Linux commands after connecting successfully connecting to sftp site (in bash script)

Tags: bash

As part of my bash script to connect to an sftp server (below - it connects with my nominated private key, user, domain and destination folder) but then unable to put anything onto remote folder as commands beyond connecting fail to be recognised.

```
 sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa user@sftpsite.domain.com:/home/folder
    put test.txt
    exit
```

have also tried encapsulating using here-document

```
 sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa user@sftpsite.domain.com:/home/folder
    <<-EOF
    put test.txt
    >EOF
    exit
```

again this fails.

If I create a txt file (sftp_command.txt) and add the commands in there (so: put test.txt) - then point to this txt file in the sftp command - it works.

```
sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa -b /root/scripts/sftp_command.txt user@sftpsite.domain.com:/home/folder
```

Just wanted to include in one file rather than pulling in a command from the text file

####Update####

As you can see, I'm pulling from a csv file a list of users (col1=user & col2=id) whole script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x #echo on
while IFS="," read -r col1 col2
do
        echo "user: $col1"
        echo "id: $col2"

        cd /efs/$col1/ftpout
        cp * /efs/$col1/backup
        #sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa user@sftpsite.domain.com:/home/folder
                <<EOF
                put test.txt
                exit
EOF
#rm test.txt


        done < <(tail -n +2 us_craig.csv)
```

The error i'm getting preventing successful execution is:

```
Connected to user@sftpsite.domain.com.
Changing to: /home/folder
+ IFS=,
+ read -r col1 col2
```

Comment: Why do you have `>` before `EOF`? It should just be `EOF`, either not indented or indented with a TAB character.

Comment: `exit` should be inside the here-document.

Answer (score 3):

`exit` should be inside the here-document, otherwise it will be executed by the local system, exiting the script.

The `EOF` marker shouldn't be preceded by `>`. It must be either at the beginning of the line, or if you put `-` in the `<<-EOF` line it can be indented with TAB characters (not spaces). Since it can be difficult to distinguish TAB from space, I've moved it to the left margin below.

`<<EOF` has to be at the end of the `sftp` line, not on the next line.

```
sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa user@sftpsite.domain.com:/home/folder <<EOF
    put test.txt
    exit
EOF
```

Comment: Many thanks @Barmar - I'll give that a try. That saves the the use of the additional file :)

Comment: #!/bin/bash

set -x #echo on
while IFS="," read -r col1 col2
do
        echo "user: $col1"
        echo "id: $col2"

        cd /efs/$col1/ftpout
        cp * /efs/$col1/backup
        sftp -oIdentityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa user@sftpsite.domain.com:/home/folder
                <<EOF
                put test.txt
                exit
EOF
#rm test.txt


        done < <(tail -n +2 us_craig.csv)

Comment: Don't put code in comments. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Sorry Barmar - It didn't work. Thought I would be able to provide the last part as this was the only part I saw affecting the success transfer.

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: Failure occurs with:

Comment: Connected to sftpsite.domain.com.
Changing to: /home/folder
+ IFS=,
+ read -r col1 col2

Comment: Edit the question and add the code you're trying to run.

Comment: Thanks Barmar - edited as requested.

Comment: Why is the `sftp` line commented out?

Comment: `<<EOF` has to be at the end of the command whose input is being redirected.

Comment: apologies - added from another entry I had commented out. That is correct without the #

Comment: Sorry - just saw my error - that's worked perfectly - many thanks Barmar :)